# Can I use composting in the video editor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

I use blender for some video editing and I’m wondering if I can take my effects further by using the compositor in blender. Will the compositor work if I just use a image sequence and add effects?

Comment: In the Compositor you can add an Input > Image and load the series of images or the movie you've created, it won't read in real time though

Comment: Wouldn't be faster to just try it? :) Place Image Sequence and add effect? Or is there something specific that didnt work for you?